# Angular, ng-show and relative location

Tags: angularjs, browser

Alright, so this might **either** be an Angular thing (in which case I might also be doing things completely wrong), but it could also be a browser / CSS thing.

"As simple as possible" plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/t3woLDwynHYgbRDGNZDK
Also, full code (runnable as code snippet) attached to this post.

The example should be pretty clear, though certainly not pretty or designed in any way. If you don't feel like reading the ~20 lines of code, the following is what should happen:

There is a "button", the area with the paste icon in it. When you click it, an operation starts. With it, a spinner (controlled by a variable on the scope) is shown inside the button. When the operation finishes (simulated by the $timeout in the example), a message is set on the scope (imagine a result info message) and the spinner-controlling variable is turned off.

The intent is of course that the spinner should always be rendered inside (position: relative) the box, but during a brief moment while elements are being re-compiled / re-evaluated, it's instead rendered just above the box (or somewhere in between the middle and above).

If you don't see the effect I am describing straightaway, click the "Clear state..." button and try again. Also, you can try different values for the $timeout. For me, a $timeout of ~ 20 ms pretty much always gives me a spinner above the box in Chrome. Firefox seems to require a slightly higher timeout, or it won't even render the spinner half the time.

I initially assumed this to be an effect of Angular re-evaluating the two elements one at a time (re-rendering them), which gave the browser a rendering tick or two to actually draw the spinner incorrectly while it was still showing. However:

What confuses me a bit is that by turning up the $timeout time to something like 200 ms, the problem goes away (or at least my eyes make me believe that), leading me to believe it might not be an Angular problem after all, but a rendering timing one? Perhaps the browser (Chrome in this case, but reproducable in at least Firefox as well) doesn't like hiding the element again after just a tick?

- ng-show / ng-if doesn't make a difference here.
- Changing the spinner icon for other icons (and removing the spin) doesn't make a difference.

Full code, since it seems to be required now:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.message = undefined;
  $scope.loading = false;
  
  $scope.perform = function(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();

    $scope.loading = true;

    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.message = "Some message...";
      $scope.loading = false;
    }, 35);
  };
  
  $scope.clear = function() {
    $scope.loading = false;
    delete $scope.message;
  };
});
```

```css
#element .resource {
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}

#element .resource .shadow {
  height: 124px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
  padding-top: 32px;
  color: #bbb;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#element .resource .shadow:hover {
  color: #888;
  border-color: #999;
}

#element .resource .shadow.inactive {
  color: #bbb;
  border-color: #999;
  cursor: default;
  padding-top: 48px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link data-require="font-awesome@*" data-semver="4.5.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.20"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.6" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="alert alert-info" ng-show="message">{{message}}</div>

    <div id="element">
      <div class="resource">
        <div x-ng-show="!loading" class="shadow" x-ng-click="perform($event);">
          <i class="fa fa-paste fa-2x"></i>
        </div>

        <div x-ng-show="loading" class="shadow inactive">
          <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-stack-2x text-info"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button ng-click="clear();">Clear state...</button>
  </body>
</html>
```